# When Palpatine intervenes in a lightsaber fight, why does the one he wants to win win, but prior they always seem to lose?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

I noticed something weird when recently viewing the entire saga films. It seems every time a Jedi faces a Sith by themselves they usually seem to lose, specifically Dooku vs. Anakin and Luke vs. Vader. However, it seems that every time Sidious is there the one that Sidious wants to win the dual always seems to win - why is this? Has this ever been addressed in the novels or movies?

Comment: What duels are you referring to ? Please edit the answer to be more specific. 
I remember only two duels from the movies with Palpatine being present and not participated:

1. Anakin vs. Dooku (Obi-wan incapacitated) - Dooku dies

2. Luke vs Darth Vader - Luke wins, but Vader's death is caused by his confrontation with Palpatine.

Or, maybe, the Clone wars?

Comment: Exactly those  two. Dooku beats Anakin in Episode II. Anakin beats Dooku in episode III with Palpatine present. Same as  with Luke. Luke loses to Vader in episode V but wins against Vader in episode VI with palpatine again being present.

Comment: We might need to have a little talk about the difference between "always" and "twice".

Answer (score 5):

**Duel 1: Anakin vs. Dooku** (*Revenge Of The Sith*)

Anakin won because he became more experienced and stronger in the Force since their last encounter in AoTC. Palpatine had nothing to lose regardless of the winner. If Dooku had won, nothing would change. With Anakin killing Dooku, Palpatine gained by pushing Anakin closer to the Dark Side and, eventually, to his complete subversion.

**Duel 2: Luke vs Vader** (*Return Of The Jedi*)

Again, in case Vader won, Palpatine had nothing to lose. The novelization of RoTJ hints that Palpatine tried to awaken anger in Luke, thus forcing him to accept the Dark Side, and that there was struggle in Luke between two choices: kill Vader with rage and anger (thus turning to the Dark Side) and refusing to fight his father (which he did). If Luke won by killing Vader, Palpatine would have gained a younger and stronger apprentice.

**Conclusion:** Palpatine had nothing to lose, regardless of the winner. If Vader did not decide to save Luke and did not turn on Palpatine, the latter would be the winner.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Fandom [Article on Sheev Palpatine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious#Power_and_abilities), he was exceptionally skilled in the foreseeing of the future:

> Darth Sidious was exceptionally adept at foreseeing the future, an ability which allowed him to plan for nearly any contingency.

That would give him the possibility to plan ahead the fights and give his preferred winner the circumstances required in order to win. He knew how much security detail could be overwhelmed, what environment was favourable for his favoured outcome and then could plan ahead for this circumstances come true.